# How to search for hotels online for a room with more than one bathroom?

Tags: hotels, booking.com

I tried with booking.com, and the only way seems to put in "2 bathrooms" in the name of the hotel, or simply look for apartments and hope that someone put it in the reviews or it is mentioned under the facilities. Just to make it clear, I'm not exclusively looking for apartments. It could also be suites or deluxe hotel rooms.

If there are any sites that include bathroom count (other than tripadvisor), I would very much appreciate any help I could get. I would then be able to filter out on a different site and search for their available rooms on booking.com.

Comment: In the US, unless the suite is huge/very high-end, I wouldn't expect a second bathrooms. Many hotels do allow booking two rooms connected by a door.